# Dynamically Generating Scopes with Descendants of a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, metaprogramming

I'm having problems with dynamically generating scopes for my STI model. Here is the model structure:

*app/models/unit.rb*

```
class Unit < ApplicationRecord
  def self.types
    descendants.map(&:name)
  end

  # Dynamically generate scopes for STI-related models
  types.each do |type|
    scope type.tableize.to_sym, -> { where(type: type) }
  end
end
```

*app/models/units/academy.rb*

```
class Academy < Unit
end
```

*app/models/units/faculty.rb*

```
class Faculty < Unit
end
```

*config/environment/development.rb*

```
config.eager_load = false

# Enable auto-load only for these files
Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
  Dir[
    Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**', '*.rb')
  ].each { |file| require_dependency file }
end
```

When I go to Rails console in development mode, I can easily check Unit types like this:

```
Unit.types
["Academy", "Faculty"]
```

However I can not reach the expected scopes (such as Unit.faculties, Unit.academies) because Rails can not generate scopes for me since it gets 'types' as an empty array. I mean this part of the Unit model:

```
types.each do |type|
  scope type.tableize.to_sym, -> { where(type: type) }
end
```

I can check types from console, even in development mode, but when it comes to dynamically generating scopes, types is returning an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that descendant classes are not instantiated. The following workaround will help you to achieve, what you're looking for:

```
def self.types
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map {|t| t.classify.constantize rescue nil}.compact
  descendants.map(&:name)
end
```

But personally, I don't think you need these scopes at all, since calling `all` on the descendant classes will provide the query:

`Faculty.all` is the same as `Unit.where(type: "Faculty")`

`Academy.all` is the same as `Unit.where(type: "Academy")`